# Is it possible to use a static background behind an animated canvas with mix-blend-mode?

Tags: css, animation, canvas, mix-blend-mode

I'm trying to create an animation where each element would change its colour based on the parent div's background. I'm using [pts.js](https://ptsjs.org/) to make the animation. It draws everything on a canvas.

Here's my setup: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zp8axfj0/).

After adding `mix-blend-mode: difference;` to the canvas, the whole gradient background disappears despite the fact that the canvas (#pt) has its background set to transparent. I want the animated lines to dynamically change their colour just like the static text does. How can I achieve it? Is it even possible with pure CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the gradient on top of the canvas (using a `::before` psuedo-element), and then `mix-blend-mode` will work:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  Pts.namespace(window);
  const run = Pts.quickStart("#pt", "transparent");
  let pts = new Group();
  space.add({
    start: () => {
      pts = Create.distributeRandom(space.bound, 50);
    },
    animate: (time, ftime) => {
      const perpend = new Group(
        new Pt(0, 0),
        new Pt(0, window.innerWidth)
      ).op(Line.perpendicularFromPt);
      pts.rotate2D(0.0055, space.center);
      pts.forEach((p, i) => {
        const lp = perpend(p);
        form.stroke(`rgba(255,255,255,255`, 1.01).line([p, lp]);
        form.fillOnly(`#000000`).point(p, 1);
      });
    },

  });
  space.bindMouse().bindTouch().play();
});
```

```css
html {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

#staticBg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#staticBg::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 60%);
  content: '';
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1;
}

#pt {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pts/0.8.8/pts.min.js"></script>
<div id="staticBg">
  <canvas id="pt"></canvas>
  <div class="text">TEST STRING</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your version simply doesn't show the animation. The text also isn't visible on Chromium 77.0 [That's](https://imgur.com/f59ksRZ) how it looks after running the code snippet.

Comment: Surprisingly, on Firefox it works correctly. I guess it's a problem with Chromium. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried it on Chrome (not Chromium), and it works as well. Your welcome.